# Throw Exception to Next Catch Block

Tags: php, exception

I want to catch a custom exception, do some logic on it, and if it fails, throw it to a more generic catch block. Like so:

```
class My_Exception extends Exception {
    protected $_nonFatal = false;

    public function __construct($value, $nonFatal = false) {
        $this->_nonFatal = (bool)$nonFatal;

        return parent::__construct($value);
    }

    public function isNonFatal() {
        return (bool)$this->_nonFatal;
    }
}

try {

} catch (My_Exception $e) {
    if ($e->isNonFatal) {
        // #1
        // Err gently
    }

    // #2
    // The error was fatal, so keep throwing it
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // #3
    echo 'An exception was caught with the message '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

So I catch `My_Exception`, check to see if it's a non-fatal error. If so, err gently, (section #1). If not (section #2), I want the second catch to be triggered, (section #3.) Instead, the `throw new Exception` in section #2 leaves the `try/catch/catch` all together.

I could use a switch statement on the class of `$e` but I think that's messier. Is there a standard way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If not (section #2), I want the second catch to be triggered

Try/catch blocks don't work like that - a catch block will always break out of the try/catch block; it doesn't "fall through" like switch statements can.

You'll need to wrap your code with another try/catch block.

```
try {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (My_Exception $e) {
        if ($e->isNonFatal) {
            // #1
            // Err gently
        }

        // #2
        // The error was fatal, so keep throwing it
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // #3
    echo 'An exception was caught with the message '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

---

> Is there a standard way to do this that I'm missing?

There's no real "standard" way to do this either; usually you don't generalize an exception with another exception, but if the application is correct then this is how you'd want to do it.

A better way to manage the chain of exceptions is to [pass your custom exception a the previous  exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) in the constructor. That way, there's a chance whatever picks up the exception may use `Exception.getPrevious()`, and display your exception alongside the more generic one.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatly, catch blocks cannot take care of any exception thrown inside preceding sibling catch block, even if it was thrown from another function call.
In other words, any unhandled exception thrown from inside catch block `#1` will not be visible from inside block #2 *(but will instead be handled by a even upper catch block in the call stack)*:

```
try {
    error_prone_code();
} catch (My_Exception $e) { // #1
    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) { // #2
    echo "Something bad happend: {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

**Then**, frankly, immediately nested try/catch blocks look quite ugly.
If your application logic is not too complicated, you can keep your code neat and clean using the [instanceof](http://php.net/instanceof) operator.

```
try {
    error_prone_code();
// Make sure to catch the standard Exception base class
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // instanceof operator tells if object:
    // is an instance of a specific class
    // is an instance of some class that extends the mentionned class
    // 's class implements a specific interface
    if ( ! $e instanceof My_Exception || ! $e->isNonFatal() ) {
        echo "Fatal exception arose: {$e->getMessage()}";
        // You may also throw the same exception to some catch block upper in the call stack.
        // throw $e;
    } else {
        // Gentle handling
    }
}
```